# How do I use "Modern UI" "office.com" instead of "Classic UI" "live.com"

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, microsoft365

Microsoft has 2 different front-end web clients for email, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#using-apis-from-later-requirement-sets), the newest is named "modern Outlook UI", and the former one is named "classic Outlook UI".

My Microsoft 365 subscription (and also my free old hotmail account) both re-direct to live.com and show the "classic" interface, even if I try to log in to office.com (and/or outlook.com).

My work account however, does the opposite - it redirects to office.com and shows a totally different user interface (which I assume is the "modern" UI).

How can I get my own email address which uses this modern UI?

I'm building an add-in, which I need to test under both UI's.

Here's screenshots which I think show the two?

classic:-

[image]

modern:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The modern UI is for Exchange Online: Microsoft 365 subscription (Outlook web app), Outlook.com

The work email uses the modern UI since it must be a part of a active M365 subscription.

You'll have to subscribe to M365 to see the same on your personal account.

Comment: This is almost certianly wrong.  The subscription I purchased includes "Outlook.com premium features" with at least "Enjoy a 50 GB, ad-free inbox and get advanced features in Outlook." - note how that says "Outlook.com" in the heading, not "Outlook", so it is CLEARLY promising me something special on the browser-based version of Outlook.  The question remains: how do I get access to what I purchased?  If you don't know, how do I reach an expert human who can tell me? (*not* any low-level call-center tech whos going to tell me I can't have what it says I got when I paid).

Comment: Modern UI is 100% rolled out now, So, In both the screenshots which you have shared, its the Modern UI only. The UI differences which you see are because of some additional features which are getting rolled out slowly.
Coming to the functioning of add-ins, in both the above scenarios the add-in will behave the same. UI will not impact the add-ins at all.